# open eclipse from a terminal and pass a workspace to open

Tags: command-line, terminal, console, arguments, eclipse

I want to open eclipse through terminal and i am able to do it, but when when eclipse starts it asks for the workspace directory attached the screenshot,and then there i have to specify it, i dont want this.

[image]

As i pass the **eclipse** command in the terminal, i want to pass the workspace directory along with the eclipse command followed by **OK** as prompt ask for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at `man eclipse`?

Comment: @guntbert no man eclipse does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should do:

```
eclipse -data /home/user/path/to/workspace
```

Here a [list of all eclipse command line arguments](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html).

Alternatively, if you anyhow only have one workspace, you could select a workspace in the dialog and check the box "Use this as the default and do not ask again".

Comment: The **-data** command you are passing is it eclipse specific terminal command, any relevant resource regarding this answer would be good.

Comment: Yes, it is eclipse specific. Link to all eclipse command line arguments added.

Comment: Would you mind to accept my answer if it solves your problem ?

Comment: Hi, does eclipse command by default be available in system or need to install any additional things apart from Eclipse IDE? @Alex

Comment: @RamaRaoM 'eclipse'  _is_ the eclipse binary, not just some command. So yea, if you install the Eclipse IDE, you should have the eclipse binary.